# Path to all subdirectories that do not contain any files

Tags: shell, directory, path

I know my question will sound silly to many of you, but can someone help me with a college topic?
Here is the statement: Make a shell script that receives a directory D as an argument. The script will recursively go through directory D and will look for and display the path to all subdirectories that do not contain any files (they are empty or contain only subdirectories).
It is requested not to use "find", thank you all.

Comment: Have you covered recursive functions yet? Good luck.

Comment: We only did while and for, but not how to recursively browse a directory and especially how to open folders in the directory

Comment: Did you learn how to test if a directory entry is a file or a directory? if `if [ -f "$item" ] ; then echo  "$item is a file" ; elif [ -d $item ] ; then echo "$item is a dir" ; fi`? You'll need to post some code here. We'll help you fix your best attempt to solve the problem, but we won't write it for you. Good luck.

Comment: They only taught us how to process data from a file, sorry I didn't upload code, but I really don't know how to start this problem.

Comment: Then your instructor has given you an assignment that they didn't give  you any preparation for. You should discuss this with them. OR search here with `[bash] for loop directory` and figure out some code to post. Get it to work for in one directory and then update your Q. Good luck.

Comment: I tried to talk to him but he doesn't answer, and this is an example of an exam. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script may be implemented with a recursion function:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "Usage: ./recursive.sh {path}" >&2
    exit 0
fi

D="$1"

print_recursively() {
    for f in "$1"/*; do
        echo "$f"
        if [[ -d "$f" ]] ; then
            print_recursively "$f"
        fi
    done
}

print_recursively "$D"
```

The solution may lack some details (like symlinks, unusual types of files etc), but it gives an idea of how recursive traverse can be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You were probably looking for something more complicated than this...

`find "$D" -type d -empty`

Comment: See the last sentence of the question.